# Where is faster to load PHP info, JS variable or element selector ?

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm wondering which is the better, more efficient way to store information once it is in PHP. Assuming the data *will* come from a PHP variable, and *will* ultimately be used in javascript:

1. immediately storing as js variable and then using variable in functions

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          var information = "lots and lots and lots of text";
             // and then later use...
   ```

or

2.. load it in the div and 'call' it later using jquery

```
 <div id="whatever" information="lots and lots and lots of text"></div>
```

and just call the 'information' element using jquery

Is one way better? Or am I wasting my time investigating this?

Comment: This is *likely* not your bottleneck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The fastest way is the js variable.**

It doesn't say it's the best way, that depends on your needs, but it's the fastest.

Comment: (It also doesn't say if it's "meaningfully faster".)

Comment: @pst. It doesn't create a DOM element for no reason and no need to query the DOM, _"meaningfully faster"_, guess not...

Answer (score 1):

I think using the **variable is more efficient** than using HTML element. Storing information in HTML element will take more time (I believe) as it will **parse the DOM** for getting the info. Variable can be accessed directly.